# How to send/retrieve words with accents to/from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I need this to work for a simple web form. I need special characters accurately sent/retrieved to/from the database. Currently whenever I send words with accents (eg. Patología Clínica) they return wrong (eg. PatologÃ­a ClÃ­nica). I have tried solving this by changing the database to

```
utf8mb4_spanish_ci
```

and by using this tag in my header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

And by using the following code in my PHP

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");?>
```

None of this is working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode`, set ALL YOUR FILES to utf-8 **without** BOM **OR** change the database collation to utf-8. And don't forget the tag `<meta charset="utf-8" />`.

Comment: All files are set to utf-8, database collation set to utf-8, my meta tag is  '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'. I will try with suggested utf8_encode and uff8_decode and tell you if it worked.